# Custom Listview Click function

Tags: android, android-listview, adapter

How to set `onClick` function for `custom listadapter` like this

```
   ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(Whats_Hot.this,
                                           Jobs,
                                           R.layout.whats_hot_list,
                                           new String[] { "title", "description" }, 
                                           new int[] { R.id.title_tv,R.id.desc_tv });

   setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use below method for getting click listener of item

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```